# Character arrays as files (Stringbuffers) in R

Tags: string, r, io

Is there a way to wrap a character array in a buffer object so it behaves like a file connection? For my particular use case, I happen to have an .RData file as a character array in memory (I know that sounds crazy), and would like to use the `load()` function without writing it to disk first.

Comment: Maybe checkout `textConnection()`? I'm not sure I quite understand what you are doing. A [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) would really help here.

Comment: `I happen to have an .RData file as a character array in memory` can you please re-phrase that? I didn't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`rawConnection`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/rawConnection.html) function e.g. :

```
# this in-memory ASCII .RData  contains: a = 123  and  b = 456
rDataInMem <-
"RDA2
A
2
134915
131840
1026
1
262153
1
a
14
1
123
1026
1
262153
1
b
14
1
456
254
"

# executing this line should appear a = 123  and  b = 456 in the workspace
load(file=rawConnection(object=charToRaw( rDataInMem ),open='r'))
```